# TFS 2013 Build definition giving error to access .nuget (type UnauthorizedAccessException)

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, msbuild, nuget, tfsbuild

I am facing an issue of permsission related to .nuget while I am using build definition of TFS 2013.

I have already applied 'Enable NuGet Package Restore' option in my Visual Studio solution.
*(I am using latest version of NuGet package manager.)*

I am getting an error mentioned as given screenshot.

[image]

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your build service was set to run with LOCAL SERVICE account. Right click on `C:\Builds` and make sure it has full permissions on that folder. Alternatively run the build service as a domain user account (e.g. DOMAIN-NAME\tfsbuild) or NETWORK SERVICE.